# Remote desktop disconnects when a modem/dialup connection is established

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, modem, dial-up

I remotely connect to several PC's which uses banking software. These computers perform a modem dial-up connection to the bank to get statements and account information, etc. and I usually do this remotely connecting to them using Windows Remote Desktop successfully.

I do these like for 15 PC's, some running Windows 7, other Windows XP, with no problem.

However, there is just one particular PC which, when I open the banking software and it connects to the bank, the Remote Desktop connection is lost, and then I can't do my work.

I suppose there's some miss-configuration, something in the network protocols, but I have ran a comparison to other computers and found all they have the same properties in the networking settings.

The answer I'm looking for is not what causing the problem, but where to start looking for what could be causing this situation.

Comment: can you ping the host after establishing the dialup and getting disconnected?

Comment: @FrankThomas Nope, the host became unavailable after that.